# Fundamental group of disjoint union of two solid tori.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Trying to determine the fundamental group of the following space using Van Kampen's theorem.

Let X and Y be two copies of the solid torus $\mathbb{D}^2\times \mathbb{S}^1$

Compute the fundamental group
of
$L_{1,0} := (X\sqcup Y )/(X ⊃ \mathbb{S}^1 × \mathbb{S}^1 \in (x, y) \cong (x, y) ∈ \mathbb{S}^1 × \mathbb{S}^1 ⊂ Y )$

Since $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(Y)=\mathbb{Z}$ and their intersection is a torus i.e. $\pi_1(X\cap Y)=\mathbb{Z*Z}$. I would assume that with $\pi_1(X\cap Y)= <a,b|[a,b]>$ and $\pi_1(X)=<c|>$, $\pi_1(Y)=<d|>$ that using Van Kampen's: $\pi_1(L_{1,0})=<a,b,c,d|[a,c][b,c],[a,d],[b,d]>$ but this doesn't appear to be correct.

On one hand I was also thinking that $L_{1,0}$ appears to be a subset of $\mathbb{S}^3$ which has a trivial fundamental group.

Comment: Your title is very misleading, as you're identifying the boundaries of the solid tori. Also, the stuff you've written in the definition of $L_{1,0}$ is garbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Van Kampen's theorem, you should identify what $X\cap Y\to X$ (resp. $X\cap Y\to Y$) induces on $\pi_1$.

If you look at the identification, one of the usual generating loops of $\pi_1(X\cap Y)$ (say $a$) is sent to $0$, and the other to the generator of $\pi_1(X)$.

But the thing is, it's the same loop that dies in $\pi_1(Y)$, and the same one that generates it

So you get a pushout square

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \langle a,b\mid [a,b]\rangle @>{a\mapsto 1, b\mapsto c}>> \langle c\rangle \\
@V{a\mapsto 1, b\mapsto d}VV @VVV \\
\langle d\rangle @>>> \pi_1L_{1,0}\end{CD}$

So you're taking $\langle c,d\rangle$ (the free product) and modding out by $c=d$ : you get $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, how do you see that a is sent to 0? Is it because if a goes around (inside the hole and outside) the torus and X can be contracted to a circle it will just be 0, whereas b is then the generator of the circle around X?

Comment: Yes, that's it : one of the generators is a loop around something that gets filled in the solid torus, so it becomes $0$ in the solid torus (as you say, when you shrink the solid torus to a circle, that loop gets contracted)